# How should I redefine my function variable to point to the correct function, position and index?

Tags: python, nameerror

I know this is basic, but I'm just learning and can't seem to figure this out. I've set my user_guesses function with the definition of right_answer, which returns an error because "stage" isn't defined.

I've tried looking for an answer on here, but I know that it's not that my global name is misspelled. I don't think I can eliminate this variable, since it's the only variable of the function. If it simply needs to be defined, I can't seem to figure out how - maybe it's obvious, but not to me yet.

I've tried to be as detailed as possible. Please let me know if I can clarify anything further.

Maybe I just need to reorganize my code somehow? There very well may be more issues than this one with my code, since I can't quite figure out how to effectively debug yet, but I hope you all will have mercy on me and help me to realize why user_guesses isn't right. Thanks in advance.

```
blanks = {"Easy": ['__1__', '__2__', '__3__', '__4__'], 
        "Medium": ['__1__', '__2__', '__3__', '__4__', '__5__'], 
        "Hard": ['__1__', '__2__', '__3__', '__4__', '__5__', '__6__']}

answers = {"Easy": ['modern', 'mineral', 'mathematical', 'hypotenuse'],
        "Medium": ['judgment', 'alibi', 'bargain', 'jean valjean', '24601'],
        "Hard": ['capri', 'eliza', 'enormous', 'spring', 'windowsill', 'loverly']}

Easy_ABS = answers["Easy"], blanks["Easy"], song["Easy"]

Medium_ABS = answers["Medium"], blanks["Medium"], song["Medium"]

Hard_ABS = answers["Hard"], blanks["Hard"], song["Hard"]

index = 0

#Stage Selection#

def difficulty(stage):
    if stage == 'easy':
        print "\nGreat choice! Good luck, Major-General:\n"
        return (Easy_ABS)       
    elif stage == 'medium':
        print "\nVery good! Now, who am I?:\n"
        return (Medium_ABS)             
    elif stage == 'hard':
        print "\nOoo, interesting! Enjoy the eloquent ramblings of Audrey Hepburn:\n"
        return (Hard_ABS)

def user_guesses(right_answer):
    user_input = raw_input("What's your best guess?: ")
    right_answer = difficulty(stage)[0][index]
    for answer in answers:
        if user_input == right_answer:
            return True
            print "Nice! On to the next!"
            return replace_blank(song, blank, index)
            index += 1
        else:
            print "Sorry, not quite. Try again!"
            user_guesses(user_input, right_answer)
```

Comment: you really ought to minimize the provided code that it captures your problem without all the extra crap, and then clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: Your `user_guesses` function takes `right_answer` as a parameter. And when you call it, you're passing `difficulty(stage)[0][indx]` as the argument value for that parameter. So just use that value in the function; don't try to set `right_answer = difficulty(stage)[0][index]` when that's already what it is.

Comment: Or, alternatively: It seems like you want to iterate through all the indexes in `difficulty(stage)[0]`? If so, change the parameter name to `right_answers`, and pass in `difficulty(stage)[0]` as the argument. Then,  you can use `right_answers[index]` inside the loop. You will still need to start `index = 0` at the top of the function, but after that—well, that should fix the problem you're asking about, but you may well have plenty of other bugs.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. If I can figure out how to edit, then I will eliminate extra code. I'm not sure what's unclear about what I'm trying to do though - I need to redefine my "right_answer" variable in the "user_guesses" function to point to the appropriate function(stage - easy, medium or hard depending on user input), position(answers, under ABS global definitions), and index(which answer and blank the game is on). I hope that clarifies more.

Comment: I've edited the code. Hopefully that is more concise to the issue. @abarnert Thanks for the response. The first suggestion doesn't work in the code, I just tried. The second doesn't account for the fact that - stage points to the level easy medium or hard - this level points to a group of things to recall (i.e. - the answers, blanks and song) - the **answers** and **blanks** are both lists - these two lists are what I need to iterate through as the user makes correct guesses to fill in each blank.